# Python decorator for retrying w/exponential backoff

Tags: python, error-handling, meta-programming

This is my first decorator in Python! I found some of it on the internet but have tweaked it to our needs.

Here is the couple concerns of mine:

- Multiple python version compatibility
- Is grabbing the `self` or `arg[0]` the best way to get the instance of the class?
- Any other general improvements!

Here is the decorator.

```
import logging
import time


def retry_and_catch(exceptions, tries=5, logger=None, level=logging.ERROR, logger_attr=None, delay=0, backoff=0):
    """
    Retries function up to amount of tries.

    Backoff disabled by default.

    :param exceptions: List of exceptions to catch
    :param tries: Number of attempts before raising any exceptions
    :param logger: Logger to print out to.
    :param level: Log level.
    :param logger_attr: Attribute on decorated class to get the logger ie self._logger you would give "_logger"
    :param delay: initial delay seconds
    :param backoff: backoff multiplier
    """
    def deco_retry(f):
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            max_tries = tries
            d = delay
            exs = tuple(exceptions)
            log = logger
            while max_tries > 1:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except exs as e:
                    message = "Exception {} caught, retrying {} more times.".format(e.message, max_tries)

                    # Get logger from cls instance of function
                    # Grabbing 'self'
                    instance = args[0]
                    if not log and logger_attr and hasattr(instance, logger_attr):
                        log = getattr(instance, logger_attr, None)

                    if log:
                        log.log(level, message)
                    else:
                        print(message)

                    # Sleep current delay
                    if d:
                        time.sleep(d)

                        # Increment delay
                        if backoff:
                            d *= backoff
                    max_tries -= 1

            return f(*args, **kwargs)  # Final attempt will not catch any errors.
        return f_retry
    return deco_retry
```

Here is an example usage

```
class MyClass(object):
    _logger = logging.getLogger()

    @retry_and_catch([ValueError], logger_attr='_logger', delay=1, backoff=2)
    def my_func(self):
        raise ValueError('Unable to run my_func')


c = MyClass()
print(c.my_func())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, when I start writing decorators of more than moderate complexity, and especially if they take parameters, I usually transition to writing them as classes - I find that easier to reason about and understand.

Second of all, in 100% of decorators I've ever written, I've wanted the decorator to [look like the wrapped function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper).  To do this, just use [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Next, I think you have some weirdness in your api. I would expect `logger` to default to some default logger, and I would expect `logger_attr` to only be used to override whatever that logger is.  I also don't like that you're explicitly calling `print` in the decorator - instead you should always use the logger, and if they want one that just calls print, or if that is the default, you should provide that.  As an additional note, if `logger_attr` is a string then you can simplify the implementation a bit to look like this

```
logger = getattr(instance, attr_name, logger)
logger.log(level, message)
```

Next, you've limited yourself to some pretty static forms of backoff by making it a number. Instead, make it be a generator.  Then you can do something like this

```
def doubling_backoff(start):
    if start == 0:
        start = 1
        yield start
    while True:
        start *= 2
        yield start

def no_backoff(start):
    while True:
        yield start
```

and then in your decorator, it looks like this

```
backoff_gen = backoff(delay)
while max_tries > 1:
    try:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    except exceptions as e:
        message = "Exception {} caught, retrying {} more times.".format(e.message, max_tries)

        instance = args[0]
        logger = getattr(args[0], attr_name, logger)
        logger.log(level, message)

        time.sleep(delay)
        delay = next(backoff_gen)
        max_tries -= 1
```

This lets you add much more complex backoff algorithms as needed.

Lastly, I think your comments don't really add much value to the code - reading the code is self-explanatory. I also don't think that promoting the values to local variables is worthwhile, but given that this is somewhat time sensitive then it might be. I removed that, but YMMV.

My end result looked something like this:

```
import time
import logging
import functools

class DefaultLogger(object):

    def log(self, level, message):
        print(message)        

def doubling_backoff(start):
    if start == 0:
        start = 1
        yield start
    while True:
        start *= 2
        yield start

def no_backoff(start):
    while True:
        yield start               

class RetryAndCatch(object):

    def __init__(exceptions_to_catch, num_tries=5, logger=DefaultLogger(), log_level=logging.ERROR, logger_attribute='', delay=0, backoff=no_backoff)
        self.exceptions = exceptions_to_catch
        self.max_tries = num_tries
        self.tries = num_tries
        self.logger = logger
        self.level = log_level
        self.attr_name = logger_attribute
        self.delay = delay
        self.backoff = backoff

    def __call__(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def retrier(*args, **kwargs):
            backoff_gen = self.backoff(delay)
            try:
                while self.tries > 1:
                    try:
                        return f(*args, **kwargs)
                    except self.exceptions as e:
                        message = "Exception {} caught, retrying {} more times.".format(e.message, self.tries)

                        instance = args[0]
                        self.logger = getattr(args[0], self.attr_name, self.logger)
                        self.logger.log(self.level, message)

                        time.sleep(self.delay)
                        self.delay = next(backoff_gen)
                        self.tries -= 1

                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                self.tries = self.max_tries
        return retrier
```

As an aside, I wrote a somewhat similar decorator and asked about it here [Memoizing decorator that can retry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97681/memoizing-decorator-that-can-retry), but the backoff idea is pretty cool and I might incorporate that into mine.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `backoff` library instead: https://pypi.org/project/backoff/

Also use jitters to improve performance.
See here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/exponential-backoff-and-jitter/

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What can the `backoff` library do that the in-built [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) can not?

Comment: `functools.wraps` and `backoff` serve two completely different purposes.