# Memoizing decorator with retries, part 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, meta-programming, memoization

A while ago I asked this question [Memoizing decorator that can retry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97681/memoizing-decorator-that-can-retry) and then promptly forgot about it. I more recently saw [Python decorator for retrying w/exponential backoff](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133310/python-decorator-for-retrying-w-exponential-backoff?lq=1) and wanted to add backoff, but figured I should improve what I already have first. I have taken some of the suggestions of the original, but really I've just completely reimagined it (and if I do say so myself, rather cleverly too). My biggest issue with this is that I'm not sure that my current distinction between "exceptions that get suppressed but not remembered" and "exceptions that get remembered" seems like it might be a bit confusing - is there a friendlier interface here?

```
import functools
from types import MappingProxyType as FrozenDict

class Memoizer:

    def __init__(self, retry_times=0, suppressed_exceptions=tuple(), capture_exceptions=False):
        self.retry = retry
        self.retry_times = retry_times
        self.suppressed_exceptions = suppressed_exceptions
        self.capture_exceptions = capture_exceptions

    def __call__(self, function):
        d = {}

        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs, __forget=False):
            key = (args, FrozenDict(kwargs))
            if key not in d or __forget:
                i = self.retry_times
                while i > 1:
                    try:
                        d[key] = function(*args, **kwargs)
                    except self.suppressed_exceptions:
                        continue
                    except Exception as e:
                        if self.capture_exceptions:
                            d[key] = e
                            break
                        raise
                    else:
                        break
                    i -= 1
                else:
                    # If we didn't already break out, the last attempt shouldn't suppress exceptions
                    d[key] = function(*args, **kwargs)

            return d[key]

        return wrapper
```

Comment: Why is `d` defined inside the function? I think this should erase its contents each time the function is called? I am confused as to why this works...

Comment: @Caridorc the same reason all memoizing decorators do that? Are you confused about the scope of this? The value of `d` is changed each time, but the individual `wrapper` functions are closures over `d`, so they maintain their own copies.

Comment: Why isn't `d` defined in `__init__` if you do want to set it to empty just once?

Comment: @Caridorc The cache is bound to the function rather than the arguments this way. Say you do `m = Memoizer()` you'd share the cache between functions with your suggestion, where this way the cache is made when you pass the function `fn = Memoizer()(fn)`.

Comment: @JoeWallis Yes, clear now, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a nice looking decorator you have there!

However, architecture-wise it does not look like a good idea, because your decorator has 2 responsibilities.

I see use cases for memoizing decorator and I see use cases for retry decorator.

However, there are much less use cases for memoizing retry decorator.

I'd recommend splitting it into 2 decorators you would be more likely to reuse later. For example, memoizing decorator that does not suppress any exceptions and lets higher level handle them and retry decorator knows nothing about memoization - only about exceptions.

I'd also recommend creating a base class for well-behaved decorators and inherit boilerplate from there.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is broken:

- `__forget=False` needs to be before `**kwargs`.
- `retry` is undefined. (But is not used)
- `MappingProxyType` is not hashable, and so you can't memoize it.

To fix the problem with `MappingProxyType` you can create a [hashable dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151686), which seems kinda hacky, but is better than nothing. The other two are easy fixes.

---

I don't see why you're using a class,
the only benefit that you get from it is that you can hide implementation details in it.
However `self.` is an annoyance in your current implementation, in my opinion.

Design wise, I still don't get the name `retry_times`, let's actually retry that amount rather than try that amount of times.

And I'd split the memoizer away from the retry decorator.
Being able to use say [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) would be nice.

And so I'd make the retry aspect a function,
removing where it currently adds to the cache.
changing the while loop to a for loop,
and will removing the cache.
This should get you:

```
def retry(retry_times=0, suppressed_exceptions=tuple(), capture_exceptions=False):
    def inner(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(retry_times):
                try:
                    return function(*args, **kwargs)
                except suppressed_exceptions:
                    continue
                except Exception as e:
                    if capture_exceptions:
                        return e
                    raise
            else:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return inner
```

And now you can use the retry part without the memoizing part!
After this, I'd just make a generic memoizer, without caching the `**kwargs`.
Say:

```
def memoize(fn):
    cache = {}
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, _forget=False):
        key = (args)
        if key not in cache or _forget:
            cache[key] = fn(*args)
        return cache[key]
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing those out! Luckily I fixed all of those in the latest iteration...

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, I can find no big issues.

#### `for`

I can suggest using a `for _ in range(self.retry_times)` as it is simpler than `while` (one less variable to think about) and makes it clear that you just want to repeat the block of code `retry_times` times and don't use the iteration counter in the code.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to repeat it `retry_times`, I want to repeat it `retry_times-1`, which looked weird to me

Comment: @Dannnno Why do you retry one time less than the user asks?

Comment: We try the last time, but it isn't in the loop. The last one happens outside, and we don't suppress any exceptions.

Comment: @Dannnno Ok, so use `retry_times - 1`

Comment: I intentionally chose not to do that - it is a bit of cognitive dissonance to use `retry_times - 1`. Do you have an idea for a better name, or do you think that the ease of the for loop is worth the weird `retry_times - 1`?

Comment: @Dannnno If you really are iterating one less time than specified (because the last retry is outside the loop and does not catch exceptions) I see no problem in stating so.